# Sub resources with emberjs + ember-data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

So I'm having (what i think is) a general problem w/ Ember-data. I'm wondering how to properly customize the adapter to adapt to the following situation.

Pretend I have two objects: `Post` and `Tag`

Calling `App.Post.find()` returns all the posts by `GET`ing `api.com/posts`, `App.Post.find(1)` is found at `api.com/posts/1`. This is good.

`App.Tag.find()` will return all the tags that are available at `api.com/tags`. `App.Tag.find(1)` will return the appropriate tag at the correct url. Also good.

If I create new Posts via `App.Post.createRecord({...})` It will `POST` to the correct url. The same goes for creating `Tags`. So far everything is dandy.

`Tags` on a `Post` are embedded because they are "on" that post.

```
App.Adapter.map("App.Post", {
    tags: {embedded: 'always'}
});
```

During load, Ember-data does everything right and I'm still super happy.

So my problem comes from adding a `Tag` to a `Post`. I would like to `PUT` or `POST` the tag object to `api.com/posts/1/tags` where the server will do all the server side things.

Currently,

1. Ember-data, with the `{embedded: 'always'}` config set, will send a `PUT` to `api.com/posts/1` with the entire `Post` object (with new `Tag` object included) as a JSON stringified string.
2. Without the `{embedded: 'always'}` config set, ember-data will try to `PUT` the tag object to `api.com/tags` and will send in the `Tag` object with a `post_id` parameter so the server side can do all the server side things.

I'd rather not do 1 because my server isn't set up that way. I'd rather not do 2 because `PUT/POST/GET`s on `api.com/tags` should really be for the "Tag management" portion of my application, and not really applying tags to posts. Another example of this behaviour is in the [Github v3 API for Labels & Issues](http://developer.github.com/v3/issues/labels/#add-labels-to-an-issue).

Does anyone know of a way of handling this with ember-data?
Thanks!

Comment: Having the exact same issue as we reasoned about it the same way - seems to make little sense since Ember is RESTFul, no?

Comment: Hey @andreimpop I ended up using embedded: 'load', our own ajax to commit to the server, and manipulated the ember-data state-machine manually. All of that is awefull - I plan one redoing it when this becomes true: http://emberjs.com/blog/2013/03/22/stabilizing-ember-data.html

Answer (score 1):

You might consider overriding the RESTAdapter#dirtyRecordsForHasManyChange function to manage how the Tags get treated during the transaction.

But it is a bit confusing that you don't have embedded relationships, however you don't want to perform PUT on Tags during Post model relationship changes. I'm not sure I see the problem with out-of-the-box adapter behavior.

Comment: Thanks... I'm not sure I understand the confusing part though. I do have embedded relationships... They work perfectly on load. I would just like to add Tags to a Post the way github adds labels to issues. See: http://developer.github.com/v3/issues/labels/#add-labels-to-an-issue

Comment: Sorry. Now I understand. You will want to override a bit of the JSONSerializer#addHasMany and maybe even JSONSerializer#addBelongsTo. But since you're doing it that way it causes confusion about which model is dirty (to be committed). You might end up digging pretty deep and possibly creating your own adapter.

Comment: Hey @clintjhill, don't be sorry! I really appreciate your help! Thanks again for shedding some light